# How can I get the name of the active fragment from the currently running app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, adb

I used `adb shell dumpsys activity <current_activity>` and checked the "Active Fragments" section to get a list of fragment names currently available. However, if the code is obfuscated, adb command isn't helpful because I don't receive the actual name. Is there any other way to get the fragment name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `adb shell dumpsys activity <current_package>`.
I also would like to know if there is any other way to get the fragment name.
I tried to get it from AccessibilityEvent but I didn't succed.

Comment: No, I meant the <current_activity>. I don't think there is anything we can do about the already obfuscated code.